# Markdown editing commands don't seem to work

Tags: discussion, markdown

I have found this link:
https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

And it says:

> #### Linebreaks
>
> End a line with two spaces to add a `<br/>` linebreak:
>
> How do I love thee?
> Let me count the ways

It seems to (obviously) work here.

Yet when I use it in a reply, it doesn't work.
(Why?)

Comment: This will be helpful: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165268

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comment formatting only supports a very specific subset, the commands in the block at the top. The other ones in the list, like line breaks, are exclusive to posts (questions and answers).

Comment: Thanks.   Just it is a new forum and slightly confusing to other ones I use.